# CSS style, how to set a kendo style for a dropdown list in div

Tags: css, html, kendo-ui, styles

```
                   <style >
                        .k-popup .k-item
                       {
                             font: 8px/1.8em bold Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                        }

                     </style>


          <div id="dd1" class="dd1">
            <input id="color1"  value="1" />
          </div>


          <div id="dd2" class="dd2">
            <input id="color2"  value="1" />
          </div>
```

So I want to style the kendo dropdownlist of color1 but not color2?  How would I do this?  It's doing both right now.  Both inputs are set as kendo dropdownlists later in the code

Comment: Can't you just give id of input you want to style???

Comment: Just update your as : **.k-popup .k-item .dd1 input{
                            font: 14px/1.8em bold Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;                        }**

Comment: No, it's doesn't work that way. It's only supposed to get the items inside the kendo dropdown list when it's opened I'll add more code below.  Just adding the class would change everything

Answer (score 0):

Please see below:

```
                  <style>
                    #color1
                    {
                         font: 8px/1.8em bold Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    }
                 </style>

      <div id="dd1" class="dd1">
        <input id="color1"  value="1" />
      </div>
      <div id="dd2" class="dd2">
        <input id="color2"  value="1" />
      </div>
```

Comment: $("#dd1").kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        dataSource: data

                    });   I only want to change what's in the dropdown, maybe I should ask this on the telerik forum